# How to use back navigation in a Codename One GUI Builder Application?

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a Main form with a Picker and a "check Dates" button.
After I tap the button, a new form shows with a Calendar and a "get Selected Date" button. I tap on that new button and then I go back to the Main form where I update the Picker Text using the selected date in the calendar

Question

How can I go to Main showing the "go back" transition?
Now I am using `showForm("Main",null)` but I don't like that transition.
(I don't know how to use the `showBack()` method, since I don't know how to get the Main form) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showForm` method should receive a command as an argument so this should work if you do something like:

```
showForm("Main", Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getBackCommand());
```

However if you don't have a back command on that form this might not work so a solution might be:

```
Command dummy = new Command("");
Display.getInstance().getCurrent().setBackCommand(dummy);
showForm("Main", dummy);
```

Comment: So the first line should go under the "get Selected Date" Action method and the 3 lines under beforeMain?

Comment: No. Its either/or. If the first line doesn't work for back navigation try the other 3 lines.

Comment: I get a "cannot find symbol" popup

Comment: Sorry it should have been `showForm` in the original response and not `showBack` as I typed it... The back becomes implicit with the command passed.